# SharePoint DispForm ID does not match EditForm ID (task). Workflow used to update IDs and Comment field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

Email is sent to users after travel request has been created, the field in email pulls "Current Item:ID", which then provides a link to the DispForm, the ID # matches.

/Lists/Travel Requests/DispForm.aspx?ID=145

When a task is created and the EditForm page is displayed via task email link, the ID number is different but the correct data is displayed from the DispForm.

/Lists/Workflow Tasks/EditForm.aspx?ID=167

Part of the workflow takes notes that are added to the task and updates the form, due to the IDs not matching, the fields are not updating. This used to update, I can not figure out what was changed to cause these fields to get out of sync.

Email that is created upon creation is linked to this path inside of the WF: /Travel%20Request/DispForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]

Task process email is linked to [%Task: URL%]

For what it's worth, I have the page redirecting. I followed steps similar to this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3e14ed98-5961-4ede-9e9e-6e949dcc9f60/sharepoint-redirect-newformaspx-to-editformaspx-after-the-item-has-been-added?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var origUrl = window.location.toString();
var editUrl = origUrl.replace("RedirectToEditForm","EditForm");
window.location = editUrl;
//-->
```

I am really trying to avoid JS as much as possible. Could this be causing the issue?

I have tried changing the lookup but nothing that I have tried so far has worked.

Comment: @venkat o do you have any other recommendations or ideas on what is causing this issue?

Comment: Anyone have any other comments or recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

The IDs are different because your list items are different.

`/Lists/Travel Requests/DispForm.aspx?ID=145` is a record created in your travel request list.

`/Lists/Workflow Tasks/EditForm.aspx?ID=167` is a record created in your Workflow Tasks list.

Both are different records in different lists.

Check your workflow email for "EditForm.aspx" link ID parameter is coming from the Workflow Task list versus Current Item ID

Comment: Thank you @venkat for this information. If they are different lists, with different IDs then why would data included in each of them be correct. The email that is sent when a new request is created has the same data as the task that is created. The only difference I see is the ID.  Should the new request email be added in the WF after the task instead of before? What information can I provide you to clarify?

Comment: In task process email you will see 2 links one is pointing to workflow task and another one under related item is a link to the list item. Which linking are you clicking to navigate to the list item?

Comment: I added some additional notes to the original post on where they are linking to.  I also included the code to a redirect that has been in there for a while. I had to remove one of the .jpg links due to my reputation score so I could provide the document that I followed in the past.

Comment: I hope there might mistake in JavaScript. Avoid script and navigate from the links in an email it should work.

Comment: When the task email comes through, the task ID shows and goes to the correct page. What should the new request email from the form show? I was under the impression that task and form data were handled differently, which is why I have to have a step that updates the form data from the apt step. I have the redirect from the display form to the edit form to save the managers the step of having to click on "edit item". As stated this has been working fine in the past. I can't tell what changed. Here is the WF w/ app step: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d46Tn.jpg.